# asp: fastest way for sending email?

Tags: email, asp-classic

i was wondering - what's the fastest way to mail out from asp:

i'm currently using jMail but it seems pretty slow to me.
would it be faster using CDOSYS?

i think a problem is smtp-authentification which is slowing down mailing the most.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use CDOSYS or any other free one you would find in google, **BUT** when using a non authenticated mail/smtp your messages will get to the spam and might even get to black lists

maybe the problam of the speed is in your code or maybe in the use of the smtp server that is giving priority for costumer, paying costumer, paying costumer for relay on their smtp server and that for guests